# Concatenate sequences of array elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assume we have an array of objects that have 'char' and 'pos' attrs, something like:

**[{char:a,pos:9} , {char:<,pos:3} , {char:b,pos:4} , {char:r,pos:5} , {char:>,pos:6}]**

Notice that the last four objects in the array have the following char values: < , b, r, >

I'm looking for a way to rip through the array, detect if I have a run of elements with char values that form a BR tag, and replace it with a single element. So, to aid with clarity here, I'm trying to go from:

[{char:a,pos:9},{char:<,pos:3},{char:b,pos:4},{char:r,pos:5},{char:>,pos:6}]

to:

[{char:a,pos:9},{char:<,b,r,>,pos:3}]

Comment: Do they have to be consecutive based on their position (3, 4, 5, 6) or could it be like <, x, b, r, z, >?

Comment: Also, you need to express your values in the objects as strings (wrap in quotes)

Comment: They always will be consecutive based on their position. E.g. if there IS a run of objects with char values of <,b,r,> respectivey, their positions will always be consecutive. Thanks for any input in advance!

Comment: Have you considered restructuring your data for easier access? Does it matter what the 'pos' even is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's one way to do it. There's no Regex and it's way overcomplicated in my opinion (so I'm not proud of it) but it should work for you:

```
var arr = [{char: 'a', pos: 9}, {char: '<', pos: 3}, {char: 'b', pos: 4}, {char: 'r', pos: 5}, {char:'>', pos: 6}],
    filled = {
      chars: {
        '<': false,
        'b': false,
        'r': false,
        '>': false
      },
      numFilled: 0
    },
    tempResults = {
      chars: []
    },
    results = [];

for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  var currentChar = arr[i].char,
      inFilled = filled.chars[currentChar];

  if (inFilled === false) {
    inFilled = true;
    tempResults.firstPos = tempResults.firstPos || arr[i].pos;
    tempResults.firstPos = (arr[i].pos < tempResults.firstPos) ? arr[i].pos : tempResults.firstPos;
    tempResults.chars.push(currentChar);
    filled.numFilled++;
  } else if (inFilled !== true) {
    results.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

results.push({char: tempResults.chars, pos: tempResults.firstPos});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the elements are sorted by their `pos` property.

```
function concatLineBreaks(items) {
  var tag_name = null;
  for (var i = 0, ii.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var item = items[i];
    switch (item) {
      case '<':
        tag_name = '';
        break;
      case '>':
        if (tag_name.toLowerCase() === 'br') {
          i -= 3;
          items[i]['char'] = '<br>';
          items.splice(i + 1, 3);
          tag_name = null;
        }
        break;
      default:
        if (tag_name !== null) {
          tag_name += item['char'];
        }
    }
  }
}

var items = [ ... ];
concatLineBreaks(items);
```